# Что обозначает $^F в Perl?

Tags: perl

В справке сказано:

> $SYSTEM_FD_MAX
>          $^F     The maximum system file descriptor, ordinarily 2.  System file descriptors are passed to "exec()"ed processes, while
>   higher file
>                  descriptors are not.  Also, during an "open()", system file descriptors are preserved even if the "open()" fails (ordinary
>   file
>                  descriptors are closed before the "open()" is attempted).  The close-on-exec status of a file descriptor will be
>   decided according
>                  to the value of $^F when the corresponding file, pipe, or socket was opened, not the time of the "exec()".
>
> Наибольшее значение для описателя системного файла, обычно 2.
>   Описатели системных файлов передаются в процессы, порождённые
>   "exec()", в то время как наивысшие описатели файлов нет. Также, во
>   время "open()", описатели системных файлов сохраняются даже если
>   "open()" завершается неудачно (обычно описатели файлов закрываются до
>   попыток "open()"). Состояние описателя файла при завершении exec будет
>   вычислено в соответствии значения $^F когда соответствующий файл,
>   труба или socket будут открыты, не во время "exec()".

Собственно к чему всё это нужно? И как это использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это необходимо для того, что бы можно было воздействовать на флаг close_on_exec для открываемых файловых дескрипторов (file handlers — FD). Это крайне редкие кейсы, когда запускаемому exec процессу не достаточно передать stdin/stdout. Но если вдруг найдется такая программа, которая использует несколько дополнительных файловых дескрипторов, унаследованных при запуске, то будет возможность их передать путем изменения переменной *$^F*, указав число большее чем 2, в зависимости от того, сколько FD вам необходимо передать сверх указанных двух.

Воспроизводимый пример. Создаем 2 файла:

a.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$^F=3; # Без этой строки ничего не работает.
       # Вместо 3, может 5, 10 и т.д
open(my $file, ">", "debug.txt"); # В большинстве unix систем
                                  # при открытии первого файла в программе 
                                  # он получит файловый дескриптор 3.
print "fileno: ", fileno($file), "\n"; # Убедимся в этом
exec('/usr/bin/perl', 'b.pl'); # Запустим другую программу
                               # (указать правильный путь к perl)
```

b.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(my $file, ">&=", 3); # Связать filehandle $file с 3 файловым дескриптором
print $file "message";
```

При запуске a.pl без строки `$^F=3` мы получим пустой файл *debug.txt* и сообщение об ошибке "*print() on closed filehandle $file at b.pl*". При наличии `$^F=3` ошибки не будет и в файл будет записана строка "message". Вместо b.pl может быть любая другая программа, например bash с командой `echo message >&3`